# Eclipse's Juno doesn't recover changes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I've turned to Eclipses's Juno lately , it works fine , but when I make any change to any file and run the project again : changes aren't recovered (specially for web development) , and I have to close the IDE and restart it again ; in order for the changes to take place..
I didn't encounter that in latest eclipse editions , is there a solution for that problem ?

Comment: yes - I am also getting this problem with eclipse indigo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned above:
The problem was solved after I had restarted the computer , till now I have no clue about the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've "built" your changes from the Project menu, or have automatic builds enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by this? please explain

Comment: Yes , automatic build is enabled, @Sherry automatic build is a way to tell the IDE to re-build the code after saving changes , you don't have to explicitly press Ctrl+B
Note : The problem was solved after I had restarted the computer , till now I have no clue about the cause of the problem..